# css "text-decoration: none" not working

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the `text-decoration: none` does not work in the following code. It fails to remove the underline of the word `yes`.

```css
.button {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Microsoft JhengHei', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.example.com">
  <div class="button" id="yes">
    Yes
  </div>
</a>
```

As you can see from the example below, the child can override the parent. This is contradictory to the problem above.

```css
.b {
  color: black;
}
.c {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="c">
    abc
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The OP has amended the question. His question is still not yet addressed.

Comment: You're not overriding the color but text-decoration and it doesn't inherit from the parent element.

Comment: But if text-decoration cannot be inherited, why `yes` is underlined?

Comment: Because anchor tag has default value: `text-decoration:underline`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the `a` tag has underline effect (using text-decoration:underline), So to remove this, you must remove from `a` tag not from its child element.

If you are talking like color values can be overridden from parent to child element but why not text-decoration?

This is because the text-decoration property doesn't inherit the style from its parent element but relies upon its own element.

Check [w3c reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-property).